# Setting the value of variable1 according to value of variable2

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, variable

I have a bash script which is executed as below

```
./myscript.sh --tourney --port 22456 --matchid 5
```

I have a variable named `matchteams`. Now there are list of match teams which are according to the id. How can I set the value of the variable `matchteams` according to the value of matchid.

Like the list is

```
1= "asde v/s rty"
2= "ggg v/s ddd"
3= "hhh v/s ddd"
4= "udfhi v/s dfjsn"
5= "gjhi v/s fgt"
```

Acoording to the above arguments `matchid=5` So how can it automatically set the value of `matchteams="gjhi v/s fgt"`

Here is the part of code how the arguments are set

```
while [ $# -gt 0 ] ; do
    case $1 in
       '--pub') fun2exec="loadpubserveripip" ;;
       '--tourney') fun2exec="loadtourneyserver" ;;
       '--standby') fun2exec="loadpubserverwg" ;;
       '--help') fun2exec="help" ;;
       '--port') port="$2" ; shift ;;
       '--matchid') matchid="$2" ; shift ;;
       *) echo "Argument Error, Please type bash script.sh --help for All Available Arguments"; exit 1 ;;
    esac
    shift
done

if [ -z "$fun2exec" ] ; then
    help
    exit 2
fi

if [ -z "$port" ] ; then
    echo "Please Provide Server Port 11011/22022/33033/44044/55055"
    exit 3
fi

if [ -z "$matchid" ] ; then
    echo "Please Provide MatchID"
    exit 3
fi

$fun2exec

exit 0
```

Comment: error messages should be printed to stderr: `echo "message" >&2`

Answer (score 4):

Use an array:

```bash
matchlist=(
    [1]="asde v/s rty"
    [2]="ggg v/s ddd"
    [3]="hhh v/s ddd"
    [4]="udfhi v/s dfjsn"
    [5]="gjhi v/s fgt"
)
```

The `[n]=` thing assigns strings to *specific* indexes in `bash`.  Without this, you get monotonically increasing indexes automatically, but they start at zero.

Then use this array with `matchid`:

```bash
matchteams=${matchlist[matchid]}
```

or even

```bash
matchteams=${matchlist[matchid]?Invalid match ID $matchid}
```

... where that last string would be printed if `$matchid` corresponds to a non-existent index in the `matchlist` array:

```bash
$ matchid=4
$ matchteams=${matchlist[matchid]?Invalid match ID $matchid}
$ echo "$matchteams"
udfhi v/s dfjsn
```

```bash
$ matchid=6
$ matchteams=${matchlist[matchid]?Invalid match ID $matchid}
bash: matchlist[matchid]: Invalid match ID 6
```

(The error would additionally terminate the shell if it was a script.)

Comment: When I try doing matchid 4 it just returns with saying [3] can you please check?

Comment: @ph3ro Then you are either getting the entry from the array in the wrong way or assigning the data to the array in the wrong way. You should not insert any extra spaces between `[n]=` and the subsequent string, and the string should be quoted. You should be able to copy-and-paste the code from my answer to recreate the examples I'm showing.

Comment: Thanks.. I got my error :)